# Muonic hydrogen 21 cm line?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-spin

Is there any difference between electron and muon in spin change behaviour(like with mass)?

In Muonic hydrogen the "21cm line" will have different frequency, but not of the spin difference, but again of mass, eh?

I mean that is no matter what fermionic particle sits in the Ising lattice, no difference...
or interaction energy ($J_{ij}$) will be different, but this is again because of mass?

What happens you can't have different experiments to separate spin behaviour and mass behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

The 21-cm transition is due to the interaction between spins of the electron and proton in a hydrogen atom.  Since the muon has a different magnetic dipole moment than the electron, the dipole-dipole interaction energy will be different and the equivalent transition in muonic hydrogen would have some other wavelength.

However, the time constant for the stable-hydrogen transition is so long ($10^{+15}$ s) compared to the lifetime of the muon ($10^{-6}$ s) that it's not likely to be an observable effect.

(Note to self: muonic hydrogen maser.)